# Should I always use a php Web driver to work with PHPUnit and Selenium?

Tags: php, selenium, drupal-7, phpunit

I tried to run Selenium with PHPUnit but it gives me "Invalid response while accessing the server" error. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: What version are you using?
And you are sure your server is up and running with same version nr?

Answer (score 0):

Is the selenium server started? It would appear its not running.

Comment: Yes, I had started the selenium server using Java -jar selenium-stand-alone-xxx etc.